# How to find out if caps lock is on in windows phone browser (with javascript keydown event)?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

How to detect caps lock on or off in mobile website using javascript keydown event and I can't use keypress event as it is not triggered in windows phone.

Is there any option that keypress event support by windows phone 8.

Comment: Can you add more information in your question? What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: Actually i wrote the some code in textarea keypress event and it is supported by all desktop browsers and even in android browsers but windows phone 8 browser doesnot support keypress event and it is not triggered so that only i tried keydown concept ..

Comment: [This seems to be a XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Maybe you can try to rephrase your question a bit?

Comment: i developed the website and it has javascript keypress events.while i press the keys in the textbox having the keypress event in windows phone 8 ie browser, keypress event is not triggered and i cant able to get the event.keycode in keypress event.